# Is it possible to have a static portion of an automatic variable in C++?

Tags: c++, boost, static

I would like to have piece of static memory associated with an automatic variable, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class StaticFriend {
  public:
    /**/         StaticFriend( void ) { }
} ;

class C {
  public:
    /**/         C( StaticFriend &f ) : myFriend( f ) { }
  private:
    StaticFriend &myFriend;
} ;

int
main( int argc, char **argv, char **envp )
{
    static StaticFriend  a;
    C                    aa( a );

    cout << "hello, world" << endl;

    static StaticFriend  b;
    C                    bb( b );

    cout << "goodbye, world" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The idea is that each automatic C (`aa`, `bb`) would have an associated `StaticFriend` that would be initialized once and then be able to store information between lifecycles of the corresponding C.  So in the example, there are two Cs (`aa` and `bb`) and each one has its own `StaticFriend`.

Other than having a separate StaticFriend as I've shown in my example, is there any way to accomplish this?  (I **do not** want a single static variable in the class...more like a single static variable in each class *instance*.)

My use case is for logging using `boost::log`.  I'm still trying to figure out the best way to use it, but it looks like the way filtering works, you start a log event with `open_record` (creating an automatic variable at the point of use), and if the severity or whatever is such that the record won't be emitted, no further activity happens on that log event.  But I would like to count the number of times through and collect timing statistics on the event, even it it doesn't get logged.  So I figure if my log event can tickle a static before deciding whether to continue, the static can record the minimal information I want.

Comment: **more like a single static variable in each class instance** This sounds like you need to have instance of `StaticFriend` as  a member variable of `C`.

Comment: Your question isn't really clear.  By definition, there can only be one instance of any static, but somehow you want a static that magically keeps track of many objects, independently of them.   That suggests the `StaticFriend` needs to be a `static` and also that it needs to contain data (e.g. a vector) that links to every instance of `C`.  The constructors and destructor of `C` would need to handle registration/deregistration of every instance of `C` with the `StaticFriend`.

Comment: I want one static per automatic variable -- exactly the way I wrote it -- but I'd like to have the static generated automatically somehow, so I don't have to remember to create them, delete them if I delete an automatic, and (ideally) they'd be namespaced so that each automatic instance can only talk to its own static portion.  (In my example, I could have passed `StaticFriend a` to both `aa` and `bb`.  But I really want `aa` and `bb` to each have their own static friend.

Comment: The `StaticFriend` matches a specific automatic variable _at the source-code level_.  So even in a recursive function, an automatic variable in the current stack frame will talk to the same `StaticFriend` as all the other (same-source-line) automatic variables in all the other stack frames.

Comment: @DaveM. You'll have to declare each StaticFriend manually at function usage. To do as you want is impossible even on theoretical level - imagine how many instances of the class you have - how can you have an automatically managed static friend if you have a dynamically allocated array of them? Or imagine how many would be needed to be generated on each function call?

Comment: @DaveM.: Would the various instances of a variable in a function *template* share one “static portion”?

Comment: @DavisHerring I dunno...I'm not very familiar with templates.  I came up with a preprocessor hack that does what I want...I'll post as an answer, but I'd really rather have something cleaner (perhaps template based).

Answer (score 1):

A preprocessor hack way of doing it (with a bit of added code to show what is possible with the `StaticFriend`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class StaticFriend {
  public:
    /**/         StaticFriend( const char *w )
                   : where( w ), count( 0 )
                   {
                       cout << "create a StaticFriend at 0x" << hex << (unsigned long)this << endl;
                   }
    /**/        ~StaticFriend( void )
                   {
                       cout << "Automatic variable " << where << " came into scope " << count << " times" << endl;
                   }
    void         tickle( void ) { ++count; }

  private:
    string       where;
    unsigned     count;
} ;

class C {
  public:
    /**/         C( StaticFriend &f )
                   : myFriend( f )
                   {
                       cout << " C@0x" << hex << (unsigned long)this << " has StaticFriend at " << (unsigned long)(&myFriend) << endl;
                       myFriend.tickle( );
                   }

    /**/        ~C( void )
                   {
                       cout << "~C@0x" << hex << (unsigned long)this << endl;
                   }

  private:
    StaticFriend &myFriend;
} ;

#define str_(x) #x
#define str(x) str_(x)
#define autoC( name, ... ) static StaticFriend name##_(#name " at " __FILE__ ":" str(__LINE__)); C name( name##_ ##__VA_ARGS__ )

int
recurse( int depth )
{
    autoC( x );

    cout << "recurse( " << depth << ")" << endl;

    if (depth > 0) recurse( depth - 1 );
}

int
main( int argc, char **argv, char **envp )
{
    cout << "Hello, world" << endl;

    recurse( 3 );

    cout << "Goodbye, world" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./test
Hello, world
create a StaticFriend at 0x562fae948200
 C@0x7ffe6bab9ea8 has StaticFriend at 562fae948200
recurse( 3)
 C@0x7ffe6bab9e68 has StaticFriend at 562fae948200
recurse( 2)
 C@0x7ffe6bab9e28 has StaticFriend at 562fae948200
recurse( 1)
 C@0x7ffe6bab9de8 has StaticFriend at 562fae948200
recurse( 0)
~C@0x7ffe6bab9de8
~C@0x7ffe6bab9e28
~C@0x7ffe6bab9e68
~C@0x7ffe6bab9ea8
Goodbye, world
Automatic variable x at test.cc:51 came into scope 4 times
```